# How Can I Parameterize Page Elements for a Test?

Tags: c#, nunit

I am looking to parameterize some tests and the only thing that changes in the tests are slider elements on the page. Here is what I was thinking of doing, just not sure how to get it over the line and working. I have tried looking at different examples but they only show how to do it if you are looking for a different string in the element.
Below is my example:

```
    [TestCase(amountTab.GreaterEqual3DSSliderValue.Text, amountTab.GreaterEqual3SDSlider)]
    public void ParameterizeMoveAmountSliders(IWebElement sliderValue, IWebElement slider)
    {
        var statsPage = new AdminStatisticsPage(LufasWebManager.Driver);
        statsPage.IsAt();
        var statsDashboard = new AdminStatisticsDashboardSubpage(LufasWebManager.Driver);
        statsDashboard.IsAt();
        statsDashboard.ClickUniversalSettingsCard();
        var configurationTab = new AdminStatsConfigurationSubPage(LufasWebManager.Driver);
        configurationTab.ClickAmountTab();
        var amountTab = new AdminStatsAmountSubPage(LufasWebManager.Driver);
        LufasWebManager.WaitUntilElementExists(5000, amountTab.GreaterEqualNeg1SDSlider);
        var currentSliderValue = sliderValue;
        configurationTab.MoveSliderLeft(slider, 3);
        var updatedSliderValue = sliderValue;
        Assert.AreNotEqual(currentSliderValue, updatedSliderValue);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [`TestCaseSource`](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/testcasesource.html) attribute (or similar approach with [`TestCaseData`](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/TestCaseData.html) one). Something along the lines:

```cs
[TestCaseSource(nameof(ParameterizeMoveAmountSlidersCases))]
public void ParameterizeMoveAmountSliders(Func<AdminStatsAmountSubPage, IWebElement> sliderValue,
    Func<AdminStatsAmountSubPage, IWebElement> slider)
{
    var statsPage = new AdminStatisticsPage(LufasWebManager.Driver);
    statsPage.IsAt();
    var statsDashboard = new AdminStatisticsDashboardSubpage(LufasWebManager.Driver);
    statsDashboard.IsAt();
    statsDashboard.ClickUniversalSettingsCard();
    var configurationTab = new AdminStatsConfigurationSubPage(LufasWebManager.Driver);
    configurationTab.ClickAmountTab();
    var amountTab = new AdminStatsAmountSubPage(LufasWebManager.Driver);
    LufasWebManager.WaitUntilElementExists(5000, amountTab.GreaterEqualNeg1SDSlider);
    var currentSliderValue = sliderValue(amountTab);
    configurationTab.MoveSliderLeft(slider(amountTab), 3);
    var updatedSliderValue = sliderValue(amountTab);
    Assert.AreNotEqual(currentSliderValue, updatedSliderValue);
}

public static IEnumerable<object> ParameterizeMoveAmountSlidersCases =  new object[]
{
    new Func<AdminStatsAmountSubPage, IWebElement>[] { amountTab => amountTab.GreaterEqual3DSSliderValue.Text, amountTab => amountTab.GreaterEqual3SDSlider },
};
```

Comment: Everything is looking good except `amountTab.GreaterEqual3DSSliderValue.Text` in the lambda expression, it is returning this error. Cannot convert anonymous method block to delegate type 'delegate type' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type. Is this because I am trying to get the text value from the element?

Comment: @DarthOpto then you will need to fix the types (i.e. cast every lambda to the needed type). I was assuming that `amountTab.GreaterEqual3DSSliderValue.Text` is `IWebElement` so took shortcut.